# Using MATLAB Compiler Runtime on Chinese Windows box

Tags: c++, matlab, boost-thread, matlab-compiler, chinese-locale

Calling `<libname>Initialize()` or `<libname>InitializeWithHandlers()` is hanging when my (non-localized) software is used on a Windows 7 system with Chinese locale.  We're using MCR v7.15.

I took a dump of the process and it appears to be a deadlock inside boost thread, if I can trust the stack trace.

I tried running the program with the AppLocale tool, selecting English.

Company let our support contract lapse, and I know from experience that Mathworks won't even review your support case w/o an active contract.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like it's making system calls in `DllMain`. You should be able to look at the dump and see which thread the `boost::thread` internal is waiting on.

Comment: Hmm, I'd think DllMain would have already been called before I call the Initialize function.  Perhaps not.  Also, I was wrong about it necessarily being Chinese-related, this customer has other machines which our software runs fine on.